# Printing the return value of a function in python?

Tags: python

I don't really understand what's wrong with my snippet here, it looks pretty simple but the compiler is returning an error to me.

```
choice = input("Enter a number: ")

def fact(num):
    if(num == 0):
        return 1
    return num * fact(num-1)

factorial = fact(choice)
print("The factorial of %d is %d." % (choice, factorial))
```

The function works fine, it's just something about setting the return to a variable, or possibly an issue in my `print()` statement. I'm just coding some random things to help me understand python syntax better.
Edit: the error

```
Enter a number: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 10, in <module>
    factorial = fact(choice)
  File "practice.py", line 8, in fact
    return num * fact(num-1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `choice = float(input("Enter a number: "))` or `int` instead of `float`

Comment: Python version matters on this question. Are you using python 2.x or 3.x? And notice that  last entry in the traceback - its failing on the return from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` returns a string which you need to convert to an int.

```
choice = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/C3fXYu)

Your example [works in Python 2](https://ideone.com/pEM7EB), as `input` would try to assume the type of the entered value.

Comment: Oh I see, so input() doesn't automatically know the data type I entered after I entered it in the console? I have to manually set it if it isn't a string

Comment: @c_help123 Python 2 tries to assume the type, but Python 3 no longer does that.